# How to pull/merge request in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitlab, pull-request

We're using on-prem gitlab, using merge requests for verification of not having messed up.
Each time we wanna request merge, we have to go through the gitlab web UI.

It's not bad per sé, but it would be nice to actually open a merge/pull request from within visual studio.

Can I somehow do that from within Team Explorer, without installing an extra gitlab extension?

Would also be nice to be able to do pull requests for github projects.

Comment: Is not possible without VS extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other Git client applications like [GitKraken](https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/gitlab) have built-in support for GitLab, but Visual Studio has not (yet).

In the Visual Studio Marketplace you find [GitLab Extension for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MysticBoy.GitLabExtensionforVisualStudio). Its project description tells you, that it enriches the *Team Explorer* view in VS, but it is not specific about its capabilities and if pull requests can be created there. So you need to give it a try if needed.